# Adding our own template in N2 cms

Tags: n2cms

I need to build one site. I have markup of the template in html. And I need to include my template in the N2 cms but I couldn't find the way for it. It was simple while we try in umbraco and composite but in n2 I am confused

Answer (score 0):

This question is too general to be answered in few paragraphs. However, you might want to check "N2 CMS 2.2.1 Developer Documentation" available for download from http://n2cms.codeplex.com/releases/view/70951